# Why am I getting the error for assigning values to list here in python?

Tags: python

Instead of appending a value by **list.append()** to the list , Why can;t I assign a value to it like this?

```
In [24]: def a():
   ....:     a1=[5]
   ....:     print a1[0]
   ....:     

In [25]: a()
5

In [28]: def a():
   ....:     a1=[5]
   ....:     a1[1]=12
   ....:     print a1[1]
   ....:     

In [29]: a()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dubizzle/webapps/django/dubizzle/<ipython-input-29-72f2e37b262f> in <module>()
----> 1 a()

/home/dubizzle/webapps/django/dubizzle/<ipython-input-28-681d86164e67> in a()
      1 def a():
      2     a1=[5]
----> 3     a1[1]=12
      4     print a1[1]
      5 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: You can assign to existing items in the list, but you cannot use assignment to add new items in Python.

Comment: Any solid reason for it ??or its just a rule..?

Comment: @NIleshSharma: There are plenty of good reasons to disallow assignment to non-existent cells. The most obvious is avoiding a significant class of bugs.

Comment: @NIleshSharma : think about the case -- `a=[1]; a[4]=5`.  What should be done with elements 1,2 and 3?  Python's not in the business of guessing what a reasonable default value would be for those elements.  It also (frequently) avoids special casing things (assigning to the next element in the list is a special case here) as it leads to cleaner code.

Comment: @NIleshSharma It is just a design decision. Python's designers could have opted to allow inserting an element into a non-existing position. If there is any gap, it could be filled with `None` for instance. But, IMO it makes more sense the way they actually chose.

Comment: Use `append` to add new items to the list. If you need control over which index a particular item occurs at, you should use a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a=[5]` creates a list with size 1. The following is valid:

```
a[0] = 1
```

but you cannot alter the size of the list by just assigning a value to a given, non-existing position.

You can extend the list, though, by using `append` or `+=`:

```
a.append(2)
a += [2]
```

You can also pre-allocate a list with a given size:

```
a = [0] * 4
```

That would give you a list with four elements (all zeros). After that you could change any element in the range 0-3.

As a reference, here you have some [documentation on lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) from python.org.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explanatory.

To force creating new items you could use slicing:

```
a1 = [5]
a1[1:2] = [12]
```

If you don't care about the order of elements you could use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
d[1] = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to you could create your own class that redimensions when you ask for a non-existent index (and fills the rest with `None`)

```
class mylist():
    def __init__(self,l):
        self.l = l
    def extend(self,index):
        diff = index + 1 - len(self.l)
        if diff > 0:
            self.l.extend([ None for x in range(diff) ] )
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        # self.extend(index) ## depending on your taste
        return self.l[index]
    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        self.extend(index) 
        self.l[index] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.l.__repr__()

a = mylist([0,1,2,3])
print 'List: %s' % a
# print a[5]  ### this will throw an 'list index out of range' unless you comment out the bit in __getitem__
a[5] = 5
print 'List: %s' % a
print a[5]
```

Which outputs:

```
List: [0, 1, 2, 3]
List: [0, 1, 2, 3, None, 5]
5
```

Check it out on http://pythonfiddle.com/auto-dimension-list

This is incomplete as you need to also bridge all other methods of list, not sure how to do that (probably some **getattr** ?) if some expert could chime in that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should pre fill it with None or something for adding with an index

```
myList = [None] * 10
myList[1] = 'a'
```

Since, list initially is a touple and you can't add anything without append.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1[x] = y
```

This cannot happen because if the list only contains 1 item and you try to assign `a1[3]` what is it going to assign in the other two `[1][2]` items in the list?

use the built-in methods for the types to modify them. `.append()` `.insert()`

Answer (score 0):

list.append() adds an element in the list, and a[1] = 'x' assigns some value to list item with index 1.  The problem with your code is you are trying to access a memory block which does not exist. try this instead.

```
def a():
    a1=[5, 0] 
    a1[1]=12 
    print a1[1]
```

or

```
def a()
    a1 = list('abc')
    a1[1]=12 
    print a1[1]
```